# customized thebibliography environment in tex4ht

Tags: bibliographies, tex4ht, bibitem

I am trying to create the following xml structure through tex4ht

```
<ref-list>
<title>Bibliography</title>
 <ref id="bib_ch0_001" bibid="aa"><label>[1]</label><mixed-citation publication-type="">Sample Bib text</mixed-citation></ref>
 <ref id="bib_ch0_002" bibid="ab"><label>[2]</label><mixed-citation publication-type="">Sample Bib text</mixed-citation></ref>
 <ref id="bib_ch0_003" bibid="cb"><label>[3]</label><mixed-citation publication-type="">Sample Bib text</mixed-citation></ref>
</reflist>
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{Macros}
\begin{document}

\cite{aa}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{aa}Sample Bib text

\bibitem{ab}Sample Bib text

\bibitem{ac}Sample Bib text
\end{thebibliography}
```

I have created the macros.4ht with the below structure

```
\newcount\bibcountid
\newcount\bibitemno
\ConfigureList{thebibliography}%
   {\Configure{likechapter}{}{}{}{}%
   \HCode{<ref-list>\Hnewline<title>Bibliography</title>}
   \let\en:bib=\empty}
   {\en:bib
    \Close:UntilEnd
    \HCode{</reflist>}
   }
   {\advance\bibcountid1\en:bib
    \def\en:bib{\HCode{\Hnewline</mixed-citation>\Hnewline</ref>}\let\en:bib=\empty}%
     \HCode{\Hnewline<ref id="bib_ch\thechapter_00\the\bibcountid" bibid="">}%
     \HCode{<label>}%
   }%
   {\HCode{</label><mixed-citation publication-type="">}}
```

1. I am getting the output at the same time Head is repeated like below

`<h2 class="likechapterHead">Bibliography</h2>`

`<ref-list>`

`<title>Bibliography</title>`

2. also i need to retain the original label id of `\bibitem{labelid}` in the xmltag     `<ref id="bib_ch0_001" bibid="aa">`

for this i just copied from latex.4ht and added the `\def\bibargforht{#2}' in the`\@lbibitem`

```
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{{\:SUBOff\:SUPOff\edef\:tempb{{#2}}%
   \pend:def\:tempb{\o:@lbibitem:[#1]}%
   \global\let\:temp\:tempb}%
   \def\bibargforht{#2}\setb:anc{#2}\:temp\bib:anc \let\AnchorLabel\sv:anc\ignorespaces}
```

when i am using the natbib.sty i am getting the compilation error!

How to configure these 2 points correctly in the bibliography environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following `Macros.4ht`:

```
\newcount\bibcountid
\newcount\bibitemno
\def\eattwo#1#2{}

\LinkCommand\BibItemLink{ref,href,bibid}

\def\saved:label{\the\value{\@listctr}}

\ConfigureEnv{thebibliography}{
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
   \HCode{<reflist>}%
\bgroup%
% Local redefinition for \chapter* configuration
\Configure{likechapter}{}{}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<title>}}{\HCode{</title>}}%
\Configure{toTocLink}{\eattwo}{}% to remove <a id=""> tag
\let\en:bib=\empty%
}
   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
    \HCode{</reflist>}\egroup%
   }%
{}{}

\ConfigureList{thebibliography}{}{\en:bib\Close:UntilEnd}
   {\advance\bibcountid1\en:bib%
    \def\en:bib{\HCode{\Hnewline</mixed-citation>\Hnewline}\EndBibItemLink\let\en:bib=\empty}%
\DeleteMark}%
   {}

\Configure{bibitem}{\BibItemLink[ id="bib_ch\thechapter_00\the\bibcountid"]}{\HCode{<label>[\saved:label]</label><mixed-citation publication-type="">}}
```

There are several changes:

- To get the bibliography title only once, the configuration for `\chapter*` command is locally redefined to print `<title>` element in configuration for `thebibliography` element. It is used also to insert the `<reflist>` element.

`tex4ht` linking mechanism is used to insert the `<ref>` element:

```
\LinkCommand\BibItemLink{ref,href,bibid}
 ...
 \ConfigureList{thebibliography}{}{\en:bib\Close:UntilEnd}
   {\advance\bibcountid1\en:bib%
    \def\en:bib{\HCode{\Hnewline</mixed-citation>\Hnewline}\EndBibItemLink \let\en:bib=\empty}%
\DeleteMark}%
   {}
  ...
 \Configure{bibitem}{\BibItemLink[ id="bib_ch\thechapter_00 \the\bibcountid"]}{\HCode{<label>[\saved:label]</label><mixed-citation publication-type="">}}
```

The `\LinkCommand` defines two new commands `\BibItemLink` and `\EndBibItemLink`. It inserts `<ref>` tag, with `bibid` parameter taking the `id`. We insert the `\BibItemLink` in `\Configure{bibitem}`, where linking command is expected.

```
\BibItemLink[ id="bib_ch\thechapter_00\the\bibcountid"]}
```

This will create following `<ref>` element:

```
 <ref 
  bibid="Xaa" id="bib_ch0_001"  >
```

Second part of `bibitem` configuration is used to insert the `<label>` and `<mixed-citation>`:

```
{\HCode{<label>[\saved:label]</label><mixed-citation publication-type="">}}
```

The bibitem label is removed from list configuration using `\DeleteMark`, because it would ruin our `xml` structure, so it has to be inserted manually at this place.

We must close `<mixed-citation>` and `<ref>` in the configuration of the `thebibliography` list:

```
 \ConfigureList{thebibliography}{}{\en:bib\Close:UntilEnd}
   {\advance\bibcountid1\en:bib%
    \def\en:bib{\HCode{\Hnewline</mixed-citation>\Hnewline}\EndBibItemLink \let\en:bib=\empty}%
\DeleteMark}%
```

I realize that it is not really straightforward configuration, but we must use dirty tricks sometimes if we need to follow strict `XML` requirements which differ from the LaTeX input structure.

This is the resulting `xml`:

```xml
 <reflist>


   <title><a 
 id="x1-1000"></a>Bibliography</title>
    <ref 
  bibid="Xaa" id="bib_ch0_001"  ><label>[1]</label><mixed-citation publication-type="">Sample Bib text

</mixed-citation> 
</ref>
    <ref 
  bibid="Xab" id="bib_ch0_002"  ><label>[2]</label><mixed-citation publication-type="">Sample Bib text

</mixed-citation> 
</ref>
    <ref 
  bibid="Xac" id="bib_ch0_003"  ><label>[3]</label><mixed-citation publication-type="">Sample Bib text 
</mixed-citation> 
</ref>
</reflist>
```

Comment: @michael: another one doubt what is the use of \Close:UntilEnd ?

Comment: @michael: I have few more doubts:                                        
     
1) In the original \bibitem label id is coming with preceding the letter "X" is it for linking purpose?  is it possible to delete "X"?

 
2) the \EndBibItemLink, it will automatically created the end tag </ref>, whatever the element given in the \LinkCommand\BibItemLink{ref,href,bibid}, the end tag will be crated?

Comment: @michael: when I am using \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
The opening tag is not printing in the xml file
`<ref  bibid="Xab" id="bib_ch0_002" ><label>[2]</label>mixed-citation publication-type="">` ?

Comment: @VenkatesanRamachandiran I used the `\Close:UntilEnd` because it was used in your original configuration. It is internal `tex4ht` command which is used when the output is saved in several files.

Comment: @VenkatesanRamachandiran I think the letter `X` is there to ensure that `id` is unique. It can be configured, but I can't find it how now. the `</ref>` is included automatically with `\EndBibLink`

Comment: @VenkatesanRamachandiran it seems that `natbib` breaks default bibliography configuration, it will need to be fixed in `tex4ht` sources.